# How to write validation in cakephp php model part

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3

There is a table location containing `city` and `name` columns. 
Query is:

```
$count=$this->Location->find("all",array("conditions" => array("Location.city" => '$city',"Location.area" => '$location')));
```

If condition becomes true, it has to show an error message.

In Model
 `role=>"unique"`
option is there, but it is for only one column.
But in above query its depends on two columns. How to write validation for this?

Comment: Do you think it is smart to tag *two* *different* CakePHP versions...? Please use only ONE version tag according to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to [read the documentation?](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Model::Validation::isUnique)

> You can validate that a set of fields are unique by providing multiple fields and set $or to false:

```
public $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
        'rule' => array('isUnique', array('email', 'username'), false),
        'message' => 'This username & email combination has already been used.'
    )
);
```

> Make sure to include the original field in the list of fields when making a unique rule across multiple fields.
>
> If a listed field isn’t included in the model data, then it’s treated as a null value. You may consider marking the listed fields as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple define a validation for the city field in the City model.

```
   public $validate = array(
      /* Other fields */
      ...................
      'city' => array(
          'rule' => array('isUnique', array('city', 'area'), false),
          'message' => 'City and area combination already exists.'
        )
    );
```